# how to write video and audio simultaneously using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureAudioDataOutput?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I've tried to make a video app like a vine by using "AVFoundation". Now I can save video through `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and can play.But somehow audio doesn't work and I don't know why.
I'm beginner of the iOS app so it may be not clear to explain. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say and give me some tips.

This is the code I'm using.

Setting up `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[CaptureSession addOutput:videoDataOutput];

videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA],kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                 nil];

dispatch_queue_t videoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoQueue", NULL);
[videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoQueue];

AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *audioDataOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
[CaptureSession addOutput:audioDataOutput];

dispatch_queue_t audioQueue = dispatch_queue_create("AudioQueue", NULL);
[audioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:audioQueue];
```

Setting up `AVAssetWrite` and `AVAssetWriterInput`:

```
- (void)makeWriter{
pathString = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/capture.mov"];
exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportURL.path])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportURL.path error:nil];
}
NSError* error;
writer = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:exportURL
                                   fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                      error:&error];
NSDictionary* videoSetting = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:1280], AVVideoWidthKey, 
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:720], AVVideoHeightKey,
                              nil];

videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                      outputSettings:videoSetting];


videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

// Add the audio input
AudioChannelLayout acl;
bzero( &acl, sizeof(acl));
acl.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Mono;

NSDictionary* audioOutputSettings = nil;
// Both type of audio inputs causes output video file to be corrupted.
if( NO ) {
    // should work from iphone 3GS on and from ipod 3rd generation
    audioOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC ], AVFormatIDKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 1 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 64000 ], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                           [ NSData dataWithBytes: &acl length: sizeof( acl ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                           nil];
} else {
    // should work on any device requires more space
    audioOutputSettings = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless ], AVFormatIDKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 16 ], AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 1 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                           [ NSData dataWithBytes: &acl length: sizeof( acl ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                           nil ];
}

audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                      assetWriterInputWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio
                     outputSettings: audioOutputSettings ];

audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;    
// add input
[writer addInput:videoWriterInput];
[writer addInput:audioWriterInput];

}
```

And finally the `CaptureOutput` code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
if ((isPause) && (isRecording)) { return; }
if( !CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) ){return;}
if( isRecording == YES ) {
    isWritting = YES;
    if( writer.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting  ) {
        [writer startWriting];

        [writer startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }

    if( [videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] ) {
        CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
        CMSampleBufferRef newSampleBuffer = [self offsetTimmingWithSampleBufferForVideo:sampleBuffer];
        [videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:newSampleBuffer];

        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
        CFRelease(newSampleBuffer);
    }
    writeFrames++;

}
}

- (CMSampleBufferRef)offsetTimmingWithSampleBufferForVideo:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
CMSampleBufferRef newSampleBuffer;
CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTimingInfo;
sampleTimingInfo.duration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
sampleTimingInfo.presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeMake(writeFrames, 30);
sampleTimingInfo.decodeTimeStamp = kCMTimeInvalid;

CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                      sampleBuffer,
                                      1,
                                      &sampleTimingInfo,
                                      &newSampleBuffer);


return newSampleBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is that you put all the samplebuffers into the videowriterinput. You need to put the samples coming form the audiobuffer into the audiowriterinput.

You should check out this SO questions and answer!

[performance-issues-when-using-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcaptureaudiodataout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274652/performance-issues-when-using-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcaptureaudiodataout)

Answer (score -1):

This can be useful.

http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

https://github.com/benlodotcom/MyAVControllerDemo

[streaming video FROM an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444791/streaming-video-from-an-iphone?rq=1)